# Check width of a column and adjust accordingly

Tags: jquery, css

I have written some JS and CSS that allows certain columns to be flexible and when the browser is resized (or by default) making a column thinner than it's original width then I remove the flexible ability. This works fine in this example: http://dev.driz.co.uk/FlexGrid.html as you will see as you resize the browser the window the red cell either fills the screen or becomes a fixed width. This is because you need at least one 100% cell for proper table-layout fixed to work as intended with cols.

The problem I am having though is that when I have TWO flexible columns the function runs on one of them BEFORE the other (at least I think as much) and means that only ONE column will have its flex class re-added. It's fine removing it but can't reapply the flexible state if the cell gets larger than its original. See the example here: http://dev.driz.co.uk/FlexGrid2.html

Can anyone help? Offer suggestions to improve the code to get the function to work on BOTH flexible columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code was almost spot on, you only had it in the wrong order.

Before you had it declaring multiple `updateWidth()` function declarations and binding the window resize event for as many columns that have the class `flex`, in this case being twice. This resulted in the events being fired separately one after another. So I moved that out of the `.each()` call, and put that `.each()` inside the function instead and it seems to work now.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // function declaration
    function updateWidth() {

        $('col.flex').each(function() {

            var flex = $(this);

            var original = flex.data('original');

            var flexIndex = flex.index() + 1; /* Add 1 because JS and CSS differ with indexes */

            var flexCell =  $('.uiGrid table tbody td:nth-child(' + flexIndex + ')');

            flexCell.css({'background':'#ff0000'});

            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            if(flexCell.width() < original) {
                $('col.flex').removeClass('flex-width');
            }
            else if(flexCell.width() >= original) {
                $('col.flex').addClass('flex-width');
            }
        });

    }

    // initial call
    updateWidth();

    // subsequent call upon window resize
    $(window).bind('resize', function() {
        updateWidth();
    });

});
```

I had to add another class for the flex function to work. One class to denote that the column is always flexible (`flex`) and another class to control the width of the column (`flex-width`). This means we can add/remove the flexible width without losing the fact that the column is flagged as flexible.

Another minor code tweak I made, which didn't stop it initially working but was redundant, was to remove any double-jquery'ed objects. One example was :

```
var flex = $(this); // flex is now a jquery object
var original = $(flex).data('original'); // flex is turned into a jquery object again
```

to

```
var flex = $(this); // flex is now a jquery object
var original = flex.data('original'); // flex is already a jquery object, so can reference it as a var
```

See code at : http://jsfiddle.net/GoranMottram/TysFf/1/
See demo at : http://jsfiddle.net/GoranMottram/TysFf/1/embedded/result/

Comment: It doesn't re-add the flex class when making the columns large again... As the class has been removed so therefore the code doesn't run again! That middle column **shouldn't** be flexing. It should always BE 300px wide.

Comment: Ahh, so it is. I've updated the answer, code and demo to hopefully fix that.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you do not add and remove the class, instead I would filter by the current width and if it is above your minimum width then adjust the column width as before.  Here's some quick psuedo-code:

```
if($(flexCell).width() >= original) {
    adjust width accordingly
}
```

Hope that helps!